# documents and sdks for windows phone 8 development

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm starting to develop a player for windows phone 8. I have a login on appHub and can access docs and tools for WP7 development. It seems that there are some differences between WP8 and WP7, e.g., WinRT APIs are used instead of Silverlight for player development. I wonder whether the development documents and sdks for WP8 are available now. Where can I get them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you only have SDK for Microsoft Surface.. The SDK for WP8 is still not available

Answer (score 0):

the sdk for wp8 is still not available hence you won't be able to get any material for those now.

you just have to wait.

you could still continue to develop for wp7 in the meantime and port it over to wp8 later on when the sdk is release.

Answer (score 0):

You can now download the WP8 SDK and documentation here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471